# How can I rsa-pss sign a message in Delphi

Tags: delphi, openssl, cross-platform, digital-signature

We're working on a Delphi (10.3) project, trying to sign a message with the RSA-PSS algorithm [(https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/RSA-PSS.html)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/RSA-PSS.html) using the OpenSSL libraries for Windows and Linux.

Right now, I'm stuck and not sure what else I can try.
The code runs without errors but returns an empty signature (all bytes are 0) of length 256. If the code about salt length is uncommented, the library procedure (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_pss_keygen_saltlen) returns -2, indicating that the operation is not supported. (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_pss_keygen_saltlen.html)

The key is provided by a third party and should be correct. What am I missing here?

This is what I have so far:

```
    class function TAuthenticationHelper.InternalSign_RSAPSS(const AInput: TBytes; AKey: EVP_PKEY): TBytes;
var
  mdCtx: EVP_MD_CTX;
  pkeyCtx: EVP_PKEY_CTX;
  sig: TBytes;
  iSiglen: NativeUInt;
begin
  mdCtx := EvpMdCtxNew();
  if not Assigned(mdCtx) then
    raise Exception.Create('mdCtx not assigned');

  pkeyCtx := EvpPkeyCtxNew(AKey, nil);
  if not Assigned(pkeyCtx) then
    raise Exception.Create('pkeyCtx not assigned');

  if EvpDigestSignInit(mdCtx, @pkeyCtx, EvpSha256(), nil, aKey) <= 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('DigestSignInit failed');

  if EvpPkeyCtxSetRsaPadding(pkeyCtx, RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING) <= 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('ctx set RSA padding not succeeded');

//  if EvpPkeyCtxSetRsaPssKeygenSaltlen(pkeyCtx, 32) <= 0 then
//    raise Exception.Create('ctx set saltlen failed');

  iSigLen := EvpPkeySize(aKey);
  if iSigLen <= 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('iSiglen has an incorrect value');

  if EvpDigestSignUpdate(mdCtx, @aInput[0], Length(aInput)) <= 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('DigestSignUpdate failed');

  if EvpDigestSignFinal(mdCtx, @sig[0], @iSigLen) <= 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('DigestSignFinal failed');

  SetLength(sig, iSigLen);
  Result := sig;
end;
class function TAuthenticationHelper.LoadPrivateKey(const AKey: TBytes; const aPassword: PAnsiChar; aKeyType: PAnsiChar = nil): PEVP_PKEY;
var
  LBio: PBIO;
  lDecoder: POSSL_DECODER_CTX;
  lFormat: PAnsiChar;
  lStructure: PAnsiChar;
  lPkey: PEVP_PKEY;
  lSelection: Integer;
begin
  lBio := BioNew(BioSMem);
  lPkey := nil;
  lFormat := 'PEM';
  lStructure := nil;
  lSelection := 0; // = autodetect
  try
    BioWrite(LBio, @AKey[0], Length(AKey));
    lDecoder := OsslDecoderCtxNewForPkey(@lPkey, lFormat, lStructure, aKeyType, lSelection, nil, nil);

    if lDecoder = nil then
      raise EAuthentication.Create('No suitable potential decoders found');

    if aPassword <> nil then
     OsslDecoderCtxSetPassphrase(lDecoder, @aPassword[0], Length(aPassword));
    if OsslDecoderFromBio(lDecoder, LBio) <= 0 then
      raise EAuthentication.Create('Decoding failure');

    Result := lPkey;
    
    if Result = nil then
      raise EAuthentication.Create('Unable to load private key: ' + GetLastError);
  finally
    BioFree(LBio);
  end;
end;

class function TAuthenticationHelper.Sign_RSAPSS(const AInput, AKey: TBytes; aPwd: string): TBytes;
var
  lPkey: EVP_PKEY;
  tmpBytes: TBytes;
begin
  lPkey := LoadPrivateKey(AKey, PAnsiChar(Ansistring(aPwd)), nil);
  try
    tmpBytes := CreateDigest(aInput, 'SHA256');
    Result := InternalSign_RSAPSS(tmpBytes, lPkey);
  finally
    EvpPkeyFree(lPkey);
  end;
end;

class function TAuthenticationHelper.Sign_RSAPSS(const aKeyFile, aStringToSign, aPwd: string): string;
var
  bTxt: TBytes;
  bData: TBytes;
  bSign: TBytes;
  sUtf: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  { TODO -oLies -cGeneral : Test of dit ook werkt }
  // bTxt := TFile.ReadAllBytes(aKeyFile);

  sUtf := TFile.ReadAllText(aKeyFile);
  bTxt := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sUtf);
  bData := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aStringToSign);

  bSign := Sign_RSAPSS(bData, bTxt, aPwd);

  Result := TNetEncoding.base64.EncodeBytesToString(bSign);
  // is this necessary?
  Result := StringReplace(Result, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the main reason my code was not working was I didn't set the length of the signature (sig) before calling EvpDigestSignFinal.

In addition, the commented code wasn't working because I was trying to set the saltlen for key generation.